# Different names for Isometric views

Tags: isometric

I'm working on project which have to display the isometric views of 3D objects. I have to display the four different Isometric views.

1. Display Top,Front,Right
2. Display Top,Left,Front
3. Display Top,Back,Right
4. Display Top,Left,Back

I created tools to show different views but felt difficult with naming the tools.
Are there any standard names available for those views?

Currently I'm using Iso 1,Iso 2,Iso 3 and Iso 4.

Thanks in advance.